# Выполнение условия в зависимости от наибольшего совпадения значения в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Мне необходимо определить наибольшее количество совпадений в массиве (реализовал). Затем в зависимости от того, у какой переменной больше значение - выполнить условие. (Может есть другой-способ реализации?)
В примере ниже большее значение у переменной `p`, но каким образом помимо километровых условий - можно задать условие, что если `p > всех остальных переменных`,то выполнять определённое действие ? Может есть какой-то другой-метод для таких целей? (потому-что в массиве может быть и 25 значений разных, для них всех условия писать и создавать переменные - не комильфо). То-есть в идеале какой-то метод или подход, который переберёт весь массив за одну итерацию и определит, что если у Профессионал больше совпадений - то выполняем 1-е условие, Опытный - то выполняем другое условие.

```js
var arr = ["Профессионал", "Начальный", "Опытный", "Уверенный", "Уверенный", "Профессионал", "Профессионал", ];
var n = 0; // novice
var p = 0; // proffesional
var y = 0; // sure
var o = 0; // expirienced


$.each(arr, filter)

function filter(i, val) {
  if (val == 'Начальный') {
    n++
  } else if (val == 'Опытный') {
    o++
  } else if (val == 'Уверенный') {
    y++
  } else if (val == 'Профессионал') {
    p++
  }
}

n == Math.max(n, p, y, o) ? console.log('Начальный уровень больше') : '';
o == Math.max(n, p, y, o) ? console.log('Опытный уровень больше') : '';
y == Math.max(n, p, y, o) ? console.log('Уверенный уровень больше') : '';
p == Math.max(n, p, y, o) ? console.log('Профессионал уровень больше') : '';
console.log(Math.max(n, p, y, o)) // Таким образом возвращает ответ что у p наибольшее количество вхождений.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  "Профессионал",
  "Начальный",
  "Опытный",
  "Уверенный",
  "Уверенный",
  "Профессионал",
  "Профессионал"
];
var handlers = {
  Профессионал: function() { console.log("professional"); },
  Начальный: function() { console.log("beginner"); },
  Опытный: function() { console.log("experienced"); },
  Уверенный: function() { console.log("seasoned"); }
};

// count number of times each level is repeated
var levelCounts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (!levelCounts[arr[i]])
    levelCounts[arr[i]] = 0;
  levelCounts[arr[i]]++;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(levelCounts));

// find level repeated the most 
var maxCount = 0;
var maxLevel = null;
for (var key in levelCounts) {
  if (levelCounts[key] > maxCount) {
    maxCount = levelCounts[key];
    maxLevel = key;
  }
}
console.log("[" + maxLevel + '] уровень больше:', maxCount);

// execute code for that level
handlers[maxLevel]();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["Профессионал","Начальный","Опытный","Уверенный","Уверенный","Профессионал","Профессионал",];
var arrs = arr.toString();
var n = {count:parseInt(arrs.match(/Начальный/g).length),text:"Начальных больше"};
var p = {count:parseInt(arrs.match(/Профессионал/g).length),text:"Профессионалов больше"};
var y = {count:parseInt(arrs.match(/Уверенный/g).length),text:"Уверенных больше"};
var o = {count:parseInt(arrs.match(/Опытный/g).length),text:"Опытных больше"};
var rb = [n,p,y,o];

for(var i = 0;i<rb.length;i++){
if(rb[i].count==Math.max(n.count,p.count,y.count,o.count))console.log(rb[i].text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```